# Golang unable to parse time

Tags: date, go, time

I am creating a Go script that attempts to parse date time strings.

My date time comes in from my client like

`2023-01-31T10:44:59.800`

I create a basic layout and attempt to parse with time.Parse

```
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 pm", s)
    if err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, fmt.Errorf("could not parse time %q", s)
    }
```

From this, I receive an error that the time cannot be parsed.

I have tried removing the `T` from my date time string but get the same output.

Is there something different I need for my layout? Potentially the `pm` is invalid?

I am struggling to work out the actual issue as the error is quite vague

Comment: If you have a `T` in your date, you need it in the format string too. Once you fix that the error will just basically tell you the `pm` is invalid.

Comment: Your format string doesn't match your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parse string needs to match the format of your time.

The string `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000"` includes the T, the milliseconds, and omits the ' pm'.  It will then parse the time properly as `2023-01-31 10:44:59.8 +0000 UTC`

[try it out on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/iC2VocBnYRh)